# How to overcome Unlink and uploading image error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to update and upload image in my directory simultaneously. In directory, if there is an image available, first it unlink and upload another, perfectly. But if the image does not exists (i.e, if it is first image) it unlink and uploads good too but throw an error. I am unable to understand why? 
Here is the error-

Message: unlink(D:\XAMPP\htdocs\pbulo\assets/uploads/ads_offers/): Permission denied

Filename: controllers/management.php

Line Number: 227

Backtrace:

File: D:\XAMPP\htdocs\pbulo\application\controllers\management.php
Line: 227
Function: unlink

File: D:\XAMPP\htdocs\pbulo\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Here is Controller:

```
public function frontOfferImage(){
if($this->session->userdata('login_answer') != null){
        $this->load->model('employee/employeemodel');


            $this->form_validation->set_rules('front_imgOffer', '', 'callback_front_img_offer_check');
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){

                $oldimg=$this->input->post('old_front_offer_img');

        $image_with_path = FCPATH.'assets/uploads/ads_offers/'.$oldimg;

                if(file_exists($image_with_path)){
                        unlink($image_with_path);            
                    }

            $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH.'assets/uploads/ads_offers/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'jpeg|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 100;
            $config['max_width']            = 1024;
            $config['max_height']           = 768;

           $this->upload->initialize($config);// $this->load->library('upload', $config); 

           if($this->upload->do_upload('front_imgOffer'))   // pd_img_3 is the name of input box.

            {


                $image_data = $this->upload->data();
                $offer_img_name = $image_data['file_name'];                     

                $data = array(
                        'front_img_offer'=>$offer_img_name,                     
                        );

            if(!$this->employeemodel->update_store_account($data)){

                $this->offerManagement();
                }else{
                    echo "Not Done";
                }

            }else{
                echo "not uploaded";
            }


            }else{
            $this->offerManagement();
        }


    }else{
            redirect('search');
        }
```

}

Here is View:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('management/frontOfferImage');?>
            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-lg-8 m-1">
                  <input type="file" name="front_imgOffer" class="btn-default btn-block border btn-sm">
                  <input type="hidden" name="old_front_offer_img" value="<?php echo $store['front_img_offer']; ?>" />
                  <?php echo form_error('front_imgOffer', '<div class="text text-danger">', '</div>'); ?>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-2 m-1">

            <?php echo form_submit(['type'=>'submit','class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-sm','value'=>'Set New Offer']); ?>
            </div>

            </div>

      <?php echo form_close(); ?>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try replacing your code with below code.

```
$oldimg=$this->input->post('old_front_offer_img');
if($oldimg != '') {
    $image_with_path = './assets/uploads/ads_offers/'.$oldimg;

   if(file_exists($image_with_path)){
       unlink($image_with_path);            
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `file_exists()` before trying to delete any file using `unlink()` like:

```
if( file_exists('file name with path') )
{
    unlink('file name with path')
}
```

And I don't think this is not a good approach to delete an old image, instead, you can generate your own name for the file using some random numbers of characters that are unique for every image (you can use timestamp with some random numbers to make it unique) or you can use `md5()` like:

```
$filename = md5(date('Y-m-d H:i:s:u'));
// will return daff7fff27025b113b4d2708285f0269
```

Comment: If possible can you make changes in my code or clarify it more to me.